# Could not find RETS data in TREB VOW Data Access

Tags: api, rets, phrets

**This is connection file**

```
date_default_timezone_set("Canada/Eastern");

require_once("vendor/autoload.php");
$config = new \PHRETS\Configuration;
$config->setLoginUrl('http://retsau.torontomls.net:6103/rets-treb3pv/server/login')
        ->setUsername('XXXX1')
        ->setPassword('76XXXXX')
        ->setRetsVersion('1.7');
$rets = new \PHRETS\Session($config);

$connect = $rets->Login();
echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($connect);
echo '</pre>';
if($connect)
{   echo "connetced";

else{
    echo 'not connected';
    }
```

**After connection could not find any data**

```
$results = $rets->Search('Property', 'A', '*', ['Limit' => 3, 'Select' => 'LIST_1,LIST_105,LIST_15,LIST_22,LIST_87,LIST_133,LIST_134']);
foreach ($results as $r) {
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($results);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

**I need to display this data after connection**

Comment: 3rd param should be DMQL query, not "*"
eg: ListDate=2020-11-08+

Answer (score 1):

First you should check TREB metadata, find correct field names and use them in the search. Moreover, you should send a query as 3rd argument of Search function.